# Getting Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `JPEG' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/460

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I installed imagemagick on my Mac with Ventura, running `identify` gives me the information on the delegates that are installed:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-7 Q16-HDRI x86_64 21117 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(5.0) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw tiff webp xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (4.2)
```

The following PHP8.2 code:

```
$i = new iMagick();
$i->readImage("https://www.amazingjokes.com/img/2023/644136c9deacf_pacman.jpg");
```

Gives me the error in the title:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `JPEG' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/460

I tried to format the error, but that doesn't leave the quotes in  the error they way there are.

I tried solutions given in similar questions on StackOverflow, like reinstalling imagemagick and jpeg libraries and such. Can anybody help me getting rid of this error?

Comment: It looks like imagik doesn't like the JPG/JPEG format ..  Are you sure it's completely installed?  What result do you get when you try to get supported formats?  -->`print_r( Imagick::queryFormats() )` (it returns an array of formats accepted) --  Do you see JPG/JPEG in the list?

Comment: the queryFormats returned an empty array. I think I had multiple instances running which meant PHP and the command line were both calling different instances of iMagick. I found out I had imagemagick, imagick@8.2 and imagick@8.3 installed. I removed both imagick ones and it solved my problem

Comment: I was going to suggest running `phpInfo()` next to make sure you weren't running outdated/duplicated/conflicting versions ..  Glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 0):

I kept trying to fix this problem and decided to try an older version of imagemagick. I got an error:

Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-7
because it is required by imagick@8.2 and imagick@8.3, which are currently installed.

I de-installed both imagick@8.2 and 8.3 and the above script worked as expected, so it solved my problem

I thought about removing this question altogether, but maybe it's better to leave it up in case someone runs into the same problem